# Does `max_block` take into account `base_block`?

Tags: weight, call

I'm writing a hook that will pop `Calls` out of storage and dispatch them.
I want to dispatch as many of those calls as possible in the limits of `max_block`.
My approach was to store the cumulated weight of thoses calls in a variable, and check before each new dispatch that `cumulated_weight + next_call.get_dispatch_info().weight < max_block`. This way I make sure that even in the worst case scenario, dispatching this call won't lead to an excess of weigh in the block.

My question is:
Should I use `cumulated_weight + next_call.get_dispatch_info().weight < max_block - base_block` instead ?
It's not clear in the [documentation](https://paritytech.github.io/substrate/monthly-2021-09+1/frame_system/limits/struct.BlockWeights.html) if `max_block` exist on top of `base_block` or if `base_block` is to take into account as consuming part of `max_block`.

Comment: I think max_block only refers to weights of non-reserve extrinsics and base_block refers to the base weight. And I think the closeness of the names is confusing. Probably the max_block should be named max_extrinsics_weight. So I think you are right base_weight is not included.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`on_initialize` has the advantage of being in the `Mandatory` dispatch class.
It can consume an unlimited amount of weight; even stall the chain if necessary.
This is what often happens for large runtime migrations that do not fit in one block.

In your case you want to stay within `max_block` as not to stall the chain.
Good examples for this are the [scheduler](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/blob/8fe464b8636803dea45f5e6506d56eae309942ba/frame/scheduler/src/lib.rs#L297) and [state-trie-migration](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/blob/26026d36a51c9f1c69b4f4e1503589b28e2019c6/frame/state-trie-migration/src/lib.rs#L839) pallets.
The scheduler has a pallet constant to configure a limit. Currently set to [80%](https://github.com/paritytech/polkadot/blob/016dc7297101710db0483ab6ef199e244dff711d/runtime/polkadot/src/lib.rs#L231) of `max_block`:

```rust
pub MaximumSchedulerWeight: Weight = Perbill::from_percent(80) *
        BlockWeights::get().max_block;
```

To analyze what is a good value here, you can directly look at the [BlockWeights](https://paritytech.github.io/substrate/latest/frame_system/limits/struct.BlockWeights.html) of your runtime. Just print it in a test. For Polkadot this print:

```
base_block: 53_99_176_000
max_block: 2_000_000_000_000

per_class:
    normal:
        base_extrinsic: 85_212_000
        max_extrinsic: Some(1_479_914_788_000)
        max_total: Some(1_500_000_000_000)
        reserved: Some(0)

    operational:
        base_extrinsic: 85_212_000
        max_extrinsic: Some(1_979_914_788_000)
        max_total: Some(2_000_000_000_000)
        reserved: Some(500_000_000_000)

    mandatory:
        base_extrinsic: 85_212_000
        max_extrinsic: None
        max_total: None
        reserved: None
```

Personally I am not sure if it makes sense to aim for a perfect value here, since you either:

1. Want to get it done ASAP: don't track the weight and just stall the chain. This may or may not be a good idea depending on your needs.
2. Have a preemptable task: Pick some limit like 80% and leave some room for other important extrinsics.

Hopefully this answers your question. For completeness I will still try to find out what the theoretical maximum value would be and update this answer.